# Can't find react Native app domain

Tags: react-native

I develop server app for my React Native project and I want to say to my server to trust to only my React Native app, but I can't find my app domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no concept of a domain in React Native or any other native app. Even so, checking the client's domain is not a secure way of authenticating your users. It is really easy for someone to create a script or program that pretends to send requests from your domain.

What you should do is build a login system for your users so that you can securely authenticate your users instead of your app.